# EROFS: read-only file system while creating node js function AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created one function on the AWS lambda using Node js version 6.10.
I need to create PDF file from html string and send that file in the email.
Following is my code:

```
    exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
    var toAddress = event.to;
    var fromAddress = event.from;
    var subject = event.subject;
    var MailBody = event.mailBody;
    var PDFHTML = event.PDFHTML;
    var LabelHTML = event.LabelHtml;

    var options = { format: 'Legal',"header": {
        "height": "25mm",
      }
    }

    pdf.convertHTMLString(LabelHTML, '/tmp/LabelDetails.pdf', function(err, res1) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            callback(err, false);
        }
        else
        {
            pdf.convertHTMLString(PDFHTML, '/tmp/DiagramDetails.pdf', function(err, res1) {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                    callback(null, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    merge(['/tmp/LabelDetails.pdf','/tmp/DiagramDetails.pdf'],'/tmp/Final.pdf',function(err){

                        if(err)
                        {
                            console.log(err);
                            callback(null, false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            /*Send mail code */
                            callback(null, true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

var fs = require("fs");
var pdf = require('html-to-pdf');
var merge = require('easy-pdf-merge');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var path = require("path");
```

When I try to convert the html string to the PDF file it throws the error EROFS: read only file system.

My simple node js code works perfectly fine.

After doing more research on this issue I found out that AWS gives write credentials only to the /tmp folder. So I applied file path like /tmp/FileName.pdf but still issue seems to be there.

Comment: have u found any solution?

Comment: @ChanchalPrashantTapase Unfortunately not yet. Came to know that lambda does not allow this type of access.

Comment: try using ./tmp